# How to apply `git reset HEAD~1` on the Github instead of the local repository?

Tags: git, github, git-reset

By mistake I committed changed to my `main` branch and pushed the changes to the server/Github. I want to completely get rid of the commit on GitHub.

The command `git reset HEAD~1` undo the last commit locally. But if I do `git pull` I would get the changes from the server that I want removed.

How to make Github forget about my last commit? How can I apply `git reset HEAD~1` on the server not just my local clone?

Comment: Probably you need to force-push your branch to remote after reset: `git push -f`. Latest arg is required because after reset your branch is "behind" remote one

Comment: @DmitriyVornychev `! [remote rejected]     main -> main (protected branch hook declined)` when doing `git push -f`

Comment: That means that your remote branch is under protection rule and you have no rights to overwrite commits history; see https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-protected-branches/about-protected-branches . Admins of repo (maybe it's you if it is yours) can adjust protection rule to allow force-pushes. Otherwise you are not allowed to rewrite git history at all and all you can do is "revert", but this will create a new "anti-commit" instead of forgetting last one. See also: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert